# Trying to dynamically replace a url &option value based on <input> button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace, href

I'm trying to dynamically replace a url value,  i'm using replace because i don't want the value to be duplicated on every click

I'm certainly not the best coder in the world, and i'm not sure if my syntax is valid or not.

The general idea i'm trying to accomplish below is there are several  urls on the page, only one is shown at any given time i use a slider to hide/show each url in a seamless manner.

I want to pass a location to the javascript function (it will be a number) and that function should take the location number and replace the section in all href="" on the page.

But i can't seem to get it to work.

```js
function getlocation(loc) {
  $('a').each(function() {
    var location = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).attr('href').replace("&location=100", "&location=loc");
    console.log('error');
  });
}
```

```html
<a class="button" href="#get.php&location=100">Test</a>
<br>
<br>

<a class="button" href="#get.php&location=100">Test</a>
<br>
<br>


<feildset>
  <input id="mtl" name="location" type="radio" checked>
  <label for="mtl" onclick="getlocation(mtl)">Montreal</label>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input id="frkfrt" name="location" type="radio" onclick="">
  <label for="frkfrt" onclick="getlocation(frkfrt)">Frankfurt</label>



</feildset>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `feildset` Spelling matters in programming.

Comment: Yeah, i typo'ed the tag,  but the javascript still doesn't produce the desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- frkfrt and mtl are not variables - you want to pass it as a *string*. But inline event handlers are as bad as `eval` inside HTML - attach the handler properly using Javascript instead, to make problems like these less likely.
- `replace` does not mutate the original string - strings are immutable. Instead, you need to explicitly *assign* to the `href`s in order to change them.
- In `getlocation`, you have to *concatenate* the `loc` variable with the `&location=`

```js
['mtl', 'frkfrt'].forEach(loc => {
  document.querySelector(`[for="${loc}"]`).onclick = () => getlocation(loc);
});


function getlocation(loc) {
  document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(a => {
    a.href = a.href.replace(/&location=.*$/, "&location=" + loc);
  });
}
```

```html
<a class="button" href="#get.php&location=100">Test</a>
<br>
<br>

<a class="button" href="#get.php&location=100">Test</a>
<br>
<br>


<feildset>
  <input id="mtl" name="location" type="radio" checked>
  <label for="mtl">Montreal</label>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input id="frkfrt" name="location" type="radio">
  <label for="frkfrt">Frankfurt</label>



</feildset>
```

Comment: ahh,  I see,  Is it possible to apply a regex pattern to the replace 

a.href = a.href.replace("&location=100", "&location=" + loc);

so that if &location=####  any number it will replace?

Comment: If you want to use a regular expression, you can match from the `location` to the end of the string

Comment: Ok i'm troubleshooting it  

I tried 

a.href = a.href.replace("&location=/\[[0-9]+\]/", "&location=" + loc);

using standard regex pattern dosen't work needs to be escaped i suspect

Comment: Just run the snippet. You define and use a regular expression *that's already inside a string* like that

Answer (score 0):

If I well understand what you need, try replace

```
$(this).attr('href').replace("&location=100", "&location=loc");
```

with

```
$(this).attr('href').replace("&location=100", "&location=" + loc);
```